# Make generic object instantiation more generic

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

I've got this piece of code to create new objects in a generic way:

```
var user = User.Create<User>(c => c.Name = "321X");
```

What I don't like about it is the fact I need to pass the 'generic notation' <T> for every create call. After all I create an object that I'm already referring to...

The code behind this current functionality is:

```
public class User : CreateBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CreateBase
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public static T Create<T>(Action<T> init) where T : CreateBase, new()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        obj.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        obj.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        init(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Is it possible (**and how**) to refactor my code to this, to create an object?

```
var user = User.Create(c => c.Name = "321X");
```

Thanks!

Comment: *"After all I create an object that I'm already referring to..."* - What do you mean by that exactly? How could the compiler possibly infer which derived type you want to instantiate?

Comment: That is my question... The `Where<TSource>` can work without the `<TSource>` as well right?

Comment: @321X in case of `Where<TSource>` it works because `where` is already defined on `IEnumerable<TSource>` so when you write e.g `new List<int>().Where(i => ...` the compiler already knows that the `TSoruce` type is int. Note it's also not a static method like in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the generic argument on the class level:

```
public abstract class CreateBase<T> where T : CreateBase<T> , new()
{
    public static T Create(Action<T> init) 
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class User : CreateBase<User>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write `var user = User.Create(c => c.Name = "321X");`

Otherwise the compiler cannot infer the type for your `Create` method without specifying the type argument.

Comment: Same as answer of @Vitaliy: I like this solution! But... it isn't working. This error is at the `class` line: `Using the generic type 'CreateBase<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: @321X thanks for the response, see my update it will work now

Answer (score 2):

You were not very far. Try this modification:

```
  public abstract class CreateBase<T> where T : CreateBase<T> , new()
  {
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public static T Create(Action<T> init)
    {
      T obj = new T();
      obj.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
      obj.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
      init(obj);
      return obj;
    }
  }

  public class User : CreateBase<User>
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

**EDIT**: Updated the code *after* I tested it on my local environment. It works now.

Comment: I like this solution! But... it isn't working. This error is at the `class` line: `Using the generic type 'CreateBase<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: Updated the code. It works now. I forgot to delete the <T> from Create.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to include this functionality in the constructor of the base class (I call it ModelBase)

```
public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; private set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; private set; }

    public ModelBase()
    {
        Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public User : ModelBase
{
    public User()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public User(string name)
        : base()
    {
        Name = name
    }

    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Creating a user the standard way will initialize the Guid and date automatically

```
var user = new User { Name = "xy };
```

---

**EDIT**

I added a second constructor with a name parameter. I you want to force the initialization of the name, drop the first parameterless constructor.

```
var user = new User("xy");
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand your solution, but it's something completely different. I don't want to initialize a new object per se.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the wrong way. Instead of getting rid of the generic argument, get rid of (needlessly) saying `User.`. Instead:

```
CreateBase.Create<User>(...)
```

No more redundancies.

Besides that, calling a static member of the base class through a derived class is an anti-pattern.

Comment: why is it an anti pattern? Thanks.

Comment: I understand your solution. I value readability and easy use of code as well. Can you explain why this is an anti-pattern? Thanks!

Comment: This pattern is flagged by tools such as Resharper and I believe even the C# compiler as a warning. It is a small stylistic error because it makes the code slightly more complex to understand. Nothing serious.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** uncomfortable with that sintax (I, honestly, don't see much problem here)

you can do the following:

```
public class User : CreateBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static User Create(Action<User> a)
    {
        return Create<User>(a); //CALL BASE CLASS GENERIC FUNCTION
    }
}
```

After you can call it in a way you would like to do that :

`var user = User.Create(c => c.Name = "321X");`